# Parsing RDF in Smalltalk

Tags: rdf, smalltalk, squeak, pharo, visualworks

Is there any example, in any Smalltalk flavour, showing how to parse a RDF file?
The only package I've seen is [Rikaiko](http://www.squeaksource.com/Rikaiko.html) with a RDFXMLReader class, but there are no references and it seems very undocummented.

Answer (score 1):

I also was looking for something like this a while ago.  Rikaiko was about it but I hadn't yet had time to really have a look at it.  These are some of the answers I got related to Pharo and Moose.

http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-project/2012-February/059235.html
As at 2012-02-07

> I am not aware of RDF support in Pharo. But, it would be definitely be cool to have one, in particular in the context of Moose. If Rakaiko has it, I would be interested. Let us know what you find.
>
> Regarding XML, the more mature solution is XMLSupport. PetitXml is nice because it is based on PetitParser which is the central parsing engine in Moose, so in the long run I would prefer to use this one. But, the collateral libraries like XPath, or the support for objects factories are not yet available for it.
>   -- Tudor Girba

Comment: Would you mind folding those URLs' answers into this answer (with attribution, obviously). Otherwise linkrot will kill the usefulness of this answer!